# Waterfall chart is breaking when I use inputs from a data table in Dash App

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I seem to be having a problem with my code where the visualization breaks after adding certain numbers to the data table as an input. Can anyone help with where I am going wrong?

In particular, the callback works fine at first until you enter certain combinations of numbers. For me, if I enter these numbers into the 'value' column, it breaks the visual and flips the axis somehow.

This causes it to break:

```
1000
100
50
-400
-50
0
```

Here is the code:

```
import dash
import pandas as pd
from dash import dash_table as dt
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
from dash.dependencies import Input
from dash.dependencies import Output
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go


df_main = pd.DataFrame({'measure' : ["relative", "relative", "relative", "relative", "relative", "total"],
                   'title' : ["Sales", "Consulting", "Net revenue", "Purchases", "Other expenses", "Profit before tax"],
                   'label' : ["+60", "+150", "Sub Total", "-40", "-20", "Total"],
                   'value' : [60, 150, 50, -40, -20, 0]})


app = dash.Dash(__name__)


app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        dt.DataTable(
            id="table-container",
            columns=[{'name': 'measure', 'id': 'measure'},
                     {'name': 'title', 'id': 'title'},
                     {'name': 'label', 'id': 'label'},
                     {'name': 'value', 'id': 'value'}],
            data=df_main.to_dict("records"),
            editable=True
        ),
        dcc.Graph(id='visual')
    ]
)


@app.callback(Output('visual', 'figure'),
              Input("table-container", "data"),
              Input("table-container", "columns"))
def display_graph(rows, columns):
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=[c['name'] for c in columns])
    
    fig = go.Figure(go.Waterfall(
        base = 0,
        orientation = "v",
        measure = df['measure'],
        x = df['title'],
        textposition = "outside",
        text = df['label'],
        y = df['value'],
        decreasing = {"marker":{"color":"#ef553b", }},
        increasing = {"marker":{"color":"#00cc96"}},
        totals = {"marker":{"color":"#636efa"}},
        connector = {"line":{"color":"rgb(63, 63, 63)"}},
    ))
    
    fig.update_layout(
            title = "Profit and loss statement 2018",
            showlegend = False
    )
    
    return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a solution after messing around for quite some time. Dash tables must have some kind of data type change as a user inputs values. Adding a line of code to convert the value field into numeric did the trick...

```
df['value'] = pd.to_numeric(df['value'])
```